# android show toast in surfacview onDraw

Tags: android, surfaceview, toast

In my game i use a surfaceview. There i update my game logic and draw on an ondraw loop.
I want to show a toast like `"good catch"` but it doesn't show. I think its because its in a loop. Even if i put it in an `if` block that limit it to show once, it doesn't work.

```
void onDraw()
{
   if(isGood) 
   Toast.makeText((Activity)getContext(), adMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered asking http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: try `this` instead of `(Activity)getContext()`

Answer (score 1):

That code should work if isGood is true.

BTW - you dont need to cast with (Activity)

Comment: thanks for the answers but it doesn't work. i think the problem has something to do it within the onDraw loop